# Magento JavaScript call returns 404

Tags: javascript, magento

On the mobile version of my site, after selecting a shipping method, and clicking this button:

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="shippingMethod.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
```

you can't continue, with this console error flagging up:

[image]

I've looked into other Magento installations and noticed that file does not exist there either, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

There is no file like that in Magento installation so that is something that probably come with some extensions or a customized theme.

Some of Magento extensions are still using `default/default` package for         `js/css/design` files. Try to look under `skin/frontend/default/default/js/` if it's not there it means that some modules are placing that js file on checkout page.

You need to look in the entire magento project for **scripts.js** file, how it is added any which `XML` file adds it.

Comment: Turns out the designers are using an Enterprise theme for a mobile CE site, could this be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Place the file in your theme folder and make sure it have permissions to access.